# Swap two ListNode* in C++

Tags: c++, recursion, singly-linked-list, swap, function-definition

Please help, I am totally lost here. This is leetcode problem no. 24, swap nodes in pairs.
I am getting this error in screeshot.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
    void recurse(ListNode* head){
        if(head!=nullptr and head->next!=nullptr){
            auto previous = head, current = head->next;
            previous->next = current->next;
            current->next = previous->next->next;
            previous->next->next = current;
            
            recurse(current);            
        }
    }
public:
    ListNode* swapPairs(ListNode* head) {
        auto front = new ListNode(0, head);
        recurse(front);
        return front->next;
    }
};
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Have you tested your code?

Comment: @gaurav Do you need to swap nodes of an existent list? If so then why are you creating a new node auto front = new ListNode(0, head)?

Comment: Please don't add errors as images. Just copy the relevant text and add it to your question.

Comment: Are you supposed to swap nodes or the value of nodes? You code can't swap nodes as you can't swap the head with the definition `swapPairs()` has.

Answer (score 2):

**UPD**: I add some comments to illustrate the OP's [correct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72327947/15213543):

```cpp
        if(head!=nullptr and head->next!=nullptr 
           and head->next->next!=nullptr){
            // p->[c]->[x]->y; swap(c, x); y can be null
            auto previous = head, current = head->next;
            // p->c->x->y
            previous->next = current->next;
            // p->x->y; c->x->y
            current->next = previous->next->next;
            // c->y; p->x->y
            previous->next->next = current;
            // p->x->c->y 
            recurse(current);            
        }
```

> original answer

```cpp
        if(head!=nullptr and head->next!=nullptr){
            auto previous = head, current = head->next;
            previous->next = current->next; // previous->next = head->next->next
            current->next = previous->next->next; // current->next = head->next->next->next

            previous->next->next = current;
            
            recurse(current);            
        }
```

In this `if` branch you only checked the `head` and `head->next` valid.

However you are attempt to invoke `head->next->next->next` later. Since `head->next->next` can be `nullptr`, your program will stop here.

You can find the right solution in the leetcode platform, and here I only reply on why this code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To swap two existent adjacent nodes of a list there is no need to create a new node as you are doing

```
auto front = new ListNode(0, head);
```

Otherwise there will be a memory leak.

Instead what you need is to pass a pointer to a node by reference.

There is already standard function `std::swap` in the C++ library that can be used in your recursion function.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

struct ListNode 
{
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 };


void clear( ListNode * &head )
{
    while ( head )
    {
        delete std::exchange( head, head->next );
    }
}

void create( ListNode * &head, const int a[], size_t n )
{
    clear( head );

    for ( ListNode **current = &head; n--; current = &( *current )->next )
    {
        *current = new ListNode( *a++ );
    }
}

std::ostream & display( const ListNode * head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const ListNode *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->val << " -> ";
    }

    return os << "null";
}

void swap( ListNode * &current )
{
    if ( current && current->next )
    {
        ListNode * &next = current->next;
        std::swap( current, next );
        std::swap( current->next, next->next );
        swap( next );
    }
}

int main()
{
    ListNode *head= nullptr;
    const int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    create( head, a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ) );
    display( head ) << '\n';

    swap( head );
    display( head ) << '\n';

    clear( head );
}
```

The program output is

```
0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7 -> 8 -> 9 -> null
1 -> 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 4 -> 7 -> 6 -> 9 -> 8 -> null
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you `tieway59`, you were right I just figured it out by myself. I was missing one more validation of `head->next->next` in `if block` of `recurse` function.
Here's my working code :

```
class Solution {
    void recurse(ListNode* head){
        if(head!=nullptr and head->next!=nullptr 
           and head->next->next!=nullptr){

            auto previous = head, current = head->next;
            previous->next = current->next;
            current->next = previous->next->next;
            previous->next->next = current;
            recurse(current);            
        }
    }
public:
    ListNode* swapPairs(ListNode* head){
        auto front = new ListNode(0, head);
        recurse(front);
        return front->next;
    }
};
```

Comment: As I wrote in my answer this approach is wrong because it is unsafe and produces a memory leak.